# Angular child component rendering using *ngFor is very slow upon data changes

Tags: angular, lodash

I am rendering child components using ngFor and applying certain filters using lodash and the result of rendering is very slow.

parent component:

```
cities = [];
```

in parent template

```
<app-city *ngFor="let city of cities"></app-city>
```

in parent component, when user clicks on button I am filtering data using lodash.

```
this.cities = _.filter(this.cities, (city) => {
    return city.distance > 5;
});
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How many cities are you filtering through?

Comment: @sandrooco less than 100

Comment: can you show us the content of your <app-city> component?

Comment: Try this: `this.filteredCities = this.cities.filter(city => city.distance > 5)` and then use the `ngFor` on `filteredCities`.
Why? Overwriting loop-bound arrays by filtering (especially with `_`) can be very slow.
Besides, please show your `app-city` comp

Comment: which browser you are checking

Comment: Is `<app-city *ngFor="let city of cities"></app-city>` the full markup or is it shortened for the question here? Are you binding to any functions in the view? What browser are you using?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes it has been shortened. I am displaying data inside city component, no functions at all.

Comment: Can you reproduce in http://stackblitz.com ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Will do research for some more time and then will try to post the full data

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use a pipe:
Insted to use .filter() you can define a pipe (using CLI command `ng g pipe citydistance`). In this ts you will have to modify the transform method in order to implement your filter. In the end, you have to import it in the ts component and add it tuo the ngFor for Example `let city of cities | citydistance`.

Hope it can help bye

Comment: Sorry, for the downvote, but using a property is the fastest way. Pipes are even discouraged in Angular docs (while I think they often a good enough option). If the question used method binding to get `cities` your answer would be good.